# How does this first function woks?

Tags: javascript, string, constructor

```
function addZero(x) {
    if (x < 10) {
        return "0" + String(x);
    } else {
        return String(x);
    }
}

function printTime() {
    var d = new Date();
    var hours = addZero(d.getHours());
    var mins = addZero(d.getMinutes());
    var secs = addZero(d.getSeconds());
    document.body.innerHTML = hours + ":" + mins + ":" + secs;
}
setInterval(printTime, 1000);
```

So vsc tells it is a string constructor but I still don't understand. Why it needs to be in capital (String), what the parameter (x) is doing and what the function is returning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The addZero function is doing exactly what its name says. It is prepending a zero to the number of hours, minutes and seconds passed as parameter `x`.

Example: Assume it is 9:23:05 when the code is run.

Then d.getHours() is 9 and this value is passed to `addZero`. As 9 is less than 10, the first part of the `if` is executed and `addZero` returns "0" + 9, i.e., the string "09", corresponding to the hour with two digits.

The same way, d.getMinutes() is 23 and this value is passed to `addZero`. But now 23 > 10 and the `else` part is executed and it returns 23.

Finally, d.getSeconds() is 5 (because the function returns only a digit if it is less than 10, i.e., 5 and not 05. Then 5 is passed to `addZero` as the parameter x. Now we have x < 10, because 5 < 10 and x receives the value 5. The first part of the `if` is executed and "0" + 5 is returned, i.e., the string "05".

Then the document.innerHTML will be set to "09" + ":" + 23 + ":" + "05", which results in "09:23:05".

Notice that if you hadn't used `addZero` and used the values of the Date methods directly, the result would be different and you would see "9:23:5" as the final result.

The `x` is a FORMAL PARAMETER, a symbol used to 'receive' a value passed to a function and allow you to manipulate the value received inside the scope of the function.

Comment: I'm glad it helped. And welcome to StackOverflow!

Answer (score 1):

`String(variable)` will parse your variable to a string.

- `false` to `'false'`
- `undefined` to `'undefined'`
- `null` to `'null'`
- `9` to `'9'`
- `'a'` to `'a'`

You can use:

- `variable + ''`
- `'' + variable`

to parse to string

Answer (score 1):

The String global object is simply a way to convert the number you have into a string, because you need to handle it as a string later. Check here for more information about String (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String).

In this particular function, `addZero`, the point is to display a leading zero on any value of hours, minutes, or seconds that is a single digit (like a digital clock would). If the number, x, is less than ten a lading zero is added. But the single digit number must first be made into a string, because you cannot have a number with the value 08. If x is greater than nine, no leading zero is necessary and the number itself is returned as a string.

Answer (score 1):

addZero changes 3 -> “03”

so, the result is
3:10:2 -> 03:10:02

x is a number, so add 0 and x equals just x.
but String() changes 3 to “3”. So it returns “03”.

Answer (score 1):

> How does this first function woks?

It checks if the input `x` is less than 10 then it will prepend '0' and return the string;
otherwise, return the input as a string.

> Why it needs to be in capital (String)

This is a correct syntax for converting a variable to a string. There are several ways of string conversion though such as `x.toString()` but all of them are different from each other more or less. So if you use something else for that matter such as `string(x)`, it will give you an error. See snippet below.

```js
console.log(string(456))
```

> what the parameter (x) is doing

It is just being forced into the string conversion process where `x` will be used to get your desired data, which is the string of `x` but the actual variable `x` of yours will still maintain its data and its datatype.

> what the function is returning.

The function will return a string. If the input is less than 10 then the string will be prepended by a '0'.